# openlayers - layer.get(key) gives "layer is not defined" error in the console

Tags: openlayers

Good morning,
why `layer.get('key')` gives "*Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: layer is not defined*" error in the console?
I would like to write the name of the layer above the data, in the popup. The key is called 'popuplayertitle'

this is the layer:

```
var lyr_WMSFogli = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: "https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php",
    attributions: " ",
    params: {
      LAYERS: "CP.CadastralZoning",
      TILED: "true",
      VERSION: "1.3.0"
    }
  }),
  title:"WMS Fogli",
  popuplayertitle: "WMS Fogli",
  permalink: "WMSFogli",
  opacity: 1.0
});
wms_layers.push([lyr_WMSFogli, 1]);
```

this is the function that gives error:

```
var onQueryWMSWFS = function (evt) {
  var coord = evt.coordinate;
  var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
  var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  if (doQueryWMSWFS) {
    for (i = 0; i < wms_layers.length; i++) {
      if (wms_layers[i][1] && wms_layers[i][0].getVisible()) {
        var url = wms_layers[i][0]
          .getSource()
          .getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection, {
            INFO_FORMAT: "text/html"
          });
        if (url) {
          content.innerHTML = "";
          fetch("https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url))
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
              overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
HERE --->     content.innerHTML += layer.get("popuplayertitle") + "<p>" + "</p>" + html;
              container.style.display = "block";
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Because you do not have a `layer` variable, your layer is `wms_layers[i][0]`

Comment: If I write wms_layers[i][0].get('popuplayertitle') I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') but I don't understand why.
The error is visible by clicking in this project https://www.ordonselli.com/z_wms_popup_layer_title/

Comment: Try leaving it as `layer` and add `var layer = wms_layers[i][0]` before calling `fetch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but if I query more than 1 layer the 'popuplayertitle' of the last layer is written above each result. How can I write the different 'popuplayertitles' defined in every layers above each result?

Comment: Do you know how to solve? Thank you

Comment: It is a javascript scope issue with the asynchronous fetch.  Simplest solution is to use `const layer` instead of `var layer` (or you could put the code inside a function (e.g. use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop).

Comment: `const layer` also solved this problem. thank you so much @Mike, the things you write to me always work perfectly.

Comment: I ask one last help to hide the `popuplayertitle` in case the wms layer is switched on but not yet visible on the map by zoom level. I wrote this but it doesn't work 
`.then ((html) => {
if (this.responseText.indexOf ('</TABLE>')! = This.responseText.lastIndexOf ('</TABLE>')) {` 
You can fix it?